# Jsoncpp FastWriter right trim

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Jsoncpp FastWriter method why last line append blank? It's for there an method Json::StreamWriterBuilder and indentation field. I how to use this method? for no lines.

Fixed please look answer.

Dont like code:

```
Json::Value root;
root["name"] = "Arda";

Json::FastWriter out;
std::cout << "'" << out.write(root) << "'" << std::endl;

// Result:
'{"name": "Arda"}
'
```

Comment: If you have a solution for your problem post as a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

I now StreamWriterBuilder  method using for nice result !

```
Json::StreamWriterBuilder wbuilder;
wbuilder["indentation"] = "";
std::cout << "'" << Json::writeString(wbuilder, root) << "'" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`FastWriter` appends an additional line feed to each result. This can be really annoying.

Although `FastWriter` is now deprecated (and should be replaced with `StreamWriterBuilder`) you can omit this ending line by using `omitEndingLineFeed()`

```
Json::FastWriter writer;
writer.omitEndingLineFeed();
return writer.write(root);
```